# select2 and multiple createSearchChoice

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Is possible to use in select2 the createSearchChoice method to create 2 choices at the same time?
I'm creating an input form for tags, if the tag does not exists I need to create two choices at the same time:
For example when the user types "missingtag" he needs to have two options

> Create a public "missingtag" tag
>   Create a private "missingtag" tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved modifying the *createSearchChoice* function in the js file

Comment: If this is your final answer which provided answer to question please tick it and it would be good if you can some explanation to your answer so other users can also refer it.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see why you should not be able to create two tags at the same time. This isnt testet and part of it is c/p from http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/.

```
    $("#tags").select2({
        createSearchChoice: function(term) { 
          return { data: {
                  {id:'public-' + term, text:'public-' + term },
                  {id:'private-' + term, text:'private-' + term}
              }
          }
    });
```